# Select limited set of fields from inner query with preserved order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I've got a SQL query which involves one-to-many relationships with `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  s0_.id,
  s0_.created_at,
  s5_.sort_order
FROM 
  surveys_submits s0_
  INNER JOIN surveys_answers s3_ ON s0_.id = s3_.submit_id
  INNER JOIN surveys_questions s4_ ON s3_.question_id = s4_.id 
  INNER JOIN surveys_questions_references s5_ ON s4_.id = s5_.question_id 
ORDER BY 
  s0_.created_at DESC, 
  s5_.sort_order ASC
```

This query returns following results:

```
id  | created_at          | sort_order
----+---------------------+-----------
218 | 2014-03-18 12:21:09 | 1
218 | 2014-03-18 12:21:09 | 2
218 | 2014-03-18 12:21:09 | 3
218 | 2014-03-18 12:21:09 | 4
218 | 2014-03-18 12:21:09 | 5
217 | 2014-03-18 12:20:57 | 1
217 | 2014-03-18 12:20:57 | 2
217 | 2014-03-18 12:20:57 | 3

             ...

214 | 2014-03-18 12:18:01 | 4
214 | 2014-03-18 12:18:01 | 5
213 | 2014-03-18 12:17:48 | 1
213 | 2014-03-18 12:17:48 | 2
213 | 2014-03-18 12:17:48 | 3
213 | 2014-03-18 12:17:48 | 4
213 | 2014-03-18 12:17:48 | 5
```

Now, I need to modify this query in a way that would return first 25 distinct ids from the begining with preserved order.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (
   SELECT ... ORDER BY ...
) inner_query
ORDER BY created_at DESC, sort_order ASC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

But obviously it doesn't work:

```
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 16:       created_at DESC, 
               ^
********** Error **********
```

...and I can't add `created_at` and `sort_order` columns to `SELECT` clause cause it would result in duplicated ids, just like the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from (
    SELECT distinct on (s0_.id)
        s0_.id,
        s0_.created_at,
        s5_.sort_order
    FROM 
        surveys_submits s0_
        INNER JOIN surveys_answers s3_ ON s0_.id = s3_.submit_id
        INNER JOIN surveys_questions s4_ ON s3_.question_id = s4_.id 
        INNER JOIN surveys_questions_references s5_ ON s4_.id = s5_.question_id 
    ORDER BY
        s0_.id,
        s0_.created_at DESC, 
        s5_.sort_order ASC
) s
order by
    created_at desc,
    sort_order ASC
limit 25
```

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

Comment: I believe `ORDER BY` clause in inner query is redundant in this case, am I right?

Comment: @Crozin The inner `order by` is fundamental. Read the quoted text of the manual

Comment: Yeah, now I see. Thank's for your help. ;)